# Excel Conditional Formatting - Highlight Date Range From Today

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting, excel-2016

I have dates in Row 1 (1/1/2019, 2/1/2019, 3/1/2019, 4/1/2019 ...)

Trying to highlight the date between 2 to 5 months from today.
For example, If today is 6/24/2019, so it should highlight 8/2019 ~ 11/2019

I've tried to do
`=AND((DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())+2,1)), MONTH(TODAY())+5)`
But I think I need something like
`MONTH(TODAY() > 2, MONTH(TODAY() < 5`

Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use de EDATE fórmula if you want to be more precise:

=AND(A1>EDATE(TODAY(),2),A1<=EDATE(TODAY(),5))

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5

Answer (score 0):

Your formula has to actually compare today's date *to something*.

Try something like this, e.g. to compare to cell `A1`:

(I'm using e.g. `TODAY()+30` instead of `DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,DAY(TODAY())` to keep it shorter but you get the idea.)

```
= AND((A1+60)>TODAY(),(A1+150)<TODAY())
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to work... Maybe because dates are 6/1/2019, 7/1/2019, 8/1/2019 and so on. Always on first of the month?

Comment: Ha, woops, I accidentally swapped the greater than/less than signs. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
It was rather very simple.
`=AND(A1>TODAY()+60,A1<=TODAY()+150)`